# OpenJPA: how to construct a GROUP BY query with a group count

Tags: java, sql, group-by, jpql, openjpa

In JPQL I want to construct the equivalent query to this:

```
select *, count(*) as finger_count from page_delta_summary 
where delta_history_id = ? and change_type = ? group by fingerprint;
```

where `fingerprint` is a varchar field in table `page_delta_summary`. What I have is this:

```
select d, count(d) as finger_count from PageDeltaSummary d 
where d.deltaHistoryId = :deltaHistoryId and d.type = :pageDeltaType 
GROUP BY d.fingerprint"
```

where `PageDeltaSummary` is my entity. But I'm getting the following exception:

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Your query on type "class com.su3analytics.sitedelta.model.PageDeltaSummary" with filter "select d, count(d) from PageDeltaSummary d where d.deltaHistoryId = :deltaHistoryId and d.type = :pageDeltaType GROUP BY d.fingerprint" is invalid.  **Your select and having clauses must only include aggregates or values that also appear in your grouping clause.**

The query works fine if I remove either count(d) as finger_count or the GROUP BY.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original SQL query doesn't make sense, therefore you can't convert in into JPQL.

I guess you want to get count of `page_delta_summary` rows satisfying `where` conditions for each `fingerprint`. If so, the SQL query looks like this:

```
select fingerprint, count(*) as finger_count from page_delta_summary  
where delta_history_id = ? and change_type = ? group by fingerprint;
```

and JPQL - like this:

```
select d.fingerprint, count(d) from PageDeltaSummary d    
where d.deltaHistoryId = :deltaHistoryId and d.type = :pageDeltaType    
GROUP BY d.fingerprint
```

These queries return pairs <`fingerprint`, `finger_count`> instead of full `page_delta_summary` rows (or entities).

Comment: thx for the reply. but why doesn't my original sql make sense? I can execute it directly no problem.

Comment: @Richard: I wondar which database supports it. Typically `SELECT` clause can only use the same fields as in `GROUP BY` clause, or aggregate functions on other fields.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, so interesting it's supported